# How do you get a Gold Slime?

Tags: slime-rancher

While playing Slime Rancher, sometimes I come across a Gold Slime, but after I try to use my vacuum, it runs into a wall and dies. I've watched a youtuber,  IHasCupquake, run into the same situation, and the same thing happened. So I have no idea how to get that amazing slime. How do I get it?

Answer (score 9):

You can't vac up Gold Slimes, but you get their plorts by hitting them with food or other plorts, or by feeding them a Gilded Ginger.

You can *sort of* capture Gold Slimes by catching a Gold Gordo with a Gordo Snare baited with a Gilded Ginger.